# Access JSON key containing colon and hyphen

Tags: mysql, json

The MySQL table has this format:

```
CREATE TABLE bar...
   ...
   foo JSON
   ...
```

The field `foo` has this content:

```
{"#:8": 0.90189, "#:34": 0.90239, "#:55": 0.90238, "#:144": 0.90219, "X:21-34": -1}
```

This command fails:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo->'$.X:21-34' != 0;
```

> Error (4,1): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around
>   character position 9.

How can I access those fields which have some **special chars** in the key name but the JSON string is still valid?

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81896

Answer (score 37, accepted):

OMG. It was very simple and is logical. This is the solution:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo->'$."X:21-34"' != 0;
```

I have to use double quotes around the key name.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks a lots